# Do you need to test your android app on different manufacturer launchers?

Tags: android, android-testing, samsung-mobile, samsung-touchwiz

I have small Android app that i want to be released in the Google Play store. During the testing process i have come up with a question - do i need to test my app with different versions of Android launcher versions for different devices like TouchWiz (Samsung) or HTC Sense Home? Is there any launcher-dependent bugs that i can catch?

Comment: As long as your following practices mentioned in the android developer guide you are good, There can hundreds of launchers out there testing for each and every one is not possible. My suggestion would be test for vanilla android launcher and release it!

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are hundreds of launchers, testing each one of them is not possible, maybe you should test for launchers like vanilla, etc. and release it.
on  android versions. Start with minsdk jelly bean to the latest(marshmallow or nougat).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can find a wide range of bugs that are device specific!

There are thousands of different android devices and it's impossible to check them manually - what you can do is to use google's testing tool called [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/).

> Firebase Test Lab for Android provides cloud-based infrastructure for
>   testing Android apps.

Basically you provide your own automation tests to your app, and with firebase you are able to test them on different vendor's devices!